# npm root - different local and global

Tags: node.js, configuration, npm

```
npm root # points to a local path
```

and

```
npm root -g # points to a global path
```

are pointing to different paths.

When I try to use a particular package, its trying to look into the local path where the package is not installed.

I tried using the following to make the local path point to the global one but no impact :(

```
npm config set prefix <global path>
```

Any clues where I am faltering? Am I suppose to update some environment variable?

Comment: You are installing the package you are trying to use globally and it is not being detectd?

Comment: yes. i am new to node related stuff and trying to get a package running. one of the steps is to run grunt <some-build-script> and it looks into bower locally in a path where it doesn't exist and then it fails.